Second cohomology group of the contact Lie algebra $K_3$
Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero and, for all $n>0$, consider the contact Lie algebra $K_{2n+1}$. It follows from Corollary 3 of the paper [V. Guillemin - S. Shnider: Some stable results on the cohomology of the classical infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 179 (1973), 275--280] that the second cohomology group $H^2(K_{2n+1}, F)$ with coefficients in the trivial module $F$ is zero, provided $n>1$.
Does this hold also for $H^2(K_{3}, F)$?

How is $K_{2n+1}$ defined?

As a vector space $K_{2n+1}$ is $F[[x_1,\ldots, x_n,y_1,\ldots, y_n, z]]$ and the Lie bracket is given by the Lagrange bracket. See the first page of the paper mentioned in the question: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1996504 . (Here the notation $(VII)_{2n+1}$ is used for this Lie algebra).

Thanks. This JSTOR link is behind paywall, when a freely available link exists at AMS site.

Yes, it is true. In fact, it is true that $H^i(K_{2n+1},F)=0$ for $0<i\le 2n$. This can be deduced from the theorem of Feigin sketched in
Feigin, B.L. Cohomology of contact Lie algebras.
(Russian) C. R. Acad. Bulgare Sci. 35 (1982), no. 8, 1029-1031.
The theorem of Feigin states that the ring $H^\bullet(K_{2n+1},F)$ is isomorphic to the cohomology ring of the inverse image of the $4n+2$-dimensional skeleton of the base of the standard classifying $Sp_{2n}\times GL_1$-bundle.
The fact that this implies the necessary vanishing is mentioned in the book of Fuchs on cohomology of infinite-dimensional Lie algebras (discussion after Theorem 2.2.17, p.118 of the English translation).
